# How to delete kde-plasma installed using tasksel in Ubuntu 20.04 completely?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu

Today I decided to only test **kde-plasma**, so I installed it on my machine, **Ubuntu 20.04**.
**How can I delete it completely**? I've tried all of commands down below but still some of it's dependencies like Konsole exists on default Ubuntu desktop. **It also caused some problems like when I move applications, It just like has a lag.**

```
sudo apt-get remove plasma-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This one also:

```
sudo tasksel remove kubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Changing out a desktop environment is no small task. There's dozens and dozens of packages that are swapped out.  KDE even uses a completely different window manager. But enough is shared that configs get wonky. You can try `purge` instead of `uninstall` in `apt`.  Honestly there might not be an easy path to restore everything as it was except a reinstall. This is why Ubuntu maintains distinct separate official flavors, mostly differentiated by the DE! If you want to test another DE, next time you can use the "Try Ubuntu" option with installation media without affecting your installation.

Comment: @Nmath thanks for your reply. So you mean, there is no way to completely remove the kde-plasma?

Comment: It sounds like you've already removed it? We can troubleshoot the individual problems left behind.  Can you identify each of them and describe the issues that are remaining?

Comment: I'm interested to know if you solved the issues left after removing KDE Plasma or if you just cut your losses in time and reinstalled Ubuntu-Gnome ?

Comment: @Trunk I migrated to Arch, then Manjaro :)) Thanks to my problem my world is much more funny :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. Open up a terminal (not Konsole, maybe gnome-terminal)
2. Type `sudo apt --purge remove 'kde*' konsole 'plasma*' 'kubuntu*' systemsettings ksudoku konversation ktorrent ksystemlog kmines kcalc partitionmanager 'gwenview*' 'kwallet*'`

   and then `sudo apt autoremove`
3. Reboot your system

I think this solved the problem for me

I found a complete solution on Ubuntu Forums, from [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1349780&p=8508684#post8508684) on [Completely remove KDE desktop](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1349780) (I did not try this):

`sudo apt-get remove akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark cdrdao dolphin dragonplayer exiv2 foomatic-db-gutenprint gdebi-kde gnupg-agent gtk2-engines-qtcurve gwenview hpijs-ppds ibus-qt4 ijsgutenprint imagemagick install-package jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaddressbook kamera kate kcm-gtk kde-icons-oxygen kde-style-qtcurve kde-window-manager kde-zeroconf kdebase-bin kdebase-data kdebase-plasma kdebase-runtime kdebase-runtime-bin-kde4 kdebase-runtime-data kdebase-runtime-data-common kdebase-workspace-bin kdebase-workspace-data kdebase-workspace-kgreet-plugins kdebase-workspace-libs4+5 kdebluetooth kdegraphics-strigi-plugins kdelibs-bin kdelibs5 kdelibs5-data kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdepasswd kdepim-groupware kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-runtime-data kdepim-runtime-libs4 kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepim-wizards kdepimlibs-data kdepimlibs5 kdesudo kdm kfind khelpcenter4 kipi-plugins klipper kmag kmail kmix kmousetool knotes konq-plugins konq-plugins-l10n konqueror konqueror-nsplugins konqueror-plugin-searchbar konqueror-plugins konsole kontact kopete korganizer kpackagekit kppp krdc krfb ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-artwork-usplash kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-konqueror-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager kwin-style-qtcurve language-selector-qt libakonadiprivate1 libao2 libaudio2 libboost-program-options1.38.0 libclucene0ldbl libepub0 libexiv2-5 libfftw3-3 libflac++6 libindicate-qt0 libjpeg-progs libk3b6 libkabcommon4 libkcddb4 libkdcraw7 libkdecorations4 libkdepim4 libkexiv2-7 libkipi6 libkleo4 libknotificationitem1 libkonq5 libkonq5-templates libkonqsidebarplugin4 libkontactinterfaces4 libkopete4 libkorundum4-ruby1.8 libkpgp4 libksane0 libksieve4 libkwineffects1 liblancelot0 liblastfm0 liblzma0 libmimelib4 libmodplug0c2 libmpcdec3 libmsn0.1 libokularcore1 libotr2 libpackagekit-glib11 libpackagekit-qt11 libplasma3 libpolkit-dbus2 libpolkit-grant2 libpolkit-qt0 libpolkit2 libpoppler-qt4-3 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqimageblitz4 libqscintilla2-5 libqt4-assistant libqt4-dbus libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-phonon libqt4-qt3support libqt4-ruby1.8 libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-webkit libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libruby1.8 libscim8c2a libsmokekde4-2 libsmokeqt4-2 libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libstrigiqtdbusclient0 libtag-extras1 libtidy-0.99-0 libvncserver0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xv0 libxine1 libxine1-bin libxine1-console libxine1-misc-plugins libxine1-x libzip1 mysql-server-core-5.1 okular okular-extra-backends openoffice.org-kde openoffice.org-style-oxygen oxygen-cursor-theme packagekit packagekit-backend-apt phonon-backend-xine pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-googlecalendar plasma-widget-indicatordisplay plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-kubuntu-qa-feedback plasma-widget-lancelot plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widget-quickaccess plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace policykit printer-applet python-kde4 python-packagekit python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip4 quassel quassel-data ruby ruby1.8 software-properties-kde soprano-daemon speedcrunch system-config-printer-kde systemsettings ttf-arphic-uming ttf-dejavu ttf-dejavu-extra update-manager-kde update-notifier-kde usb-creator-kde userconfig && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`